# Matplotlib Glitches After Window Resize using Blitting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use blitting with matplotlib to improve the performance of my plot, but am running into glitches after resizing the matplotlib window.
I have a matplotlib window showing 8 different lines plotted, along with a table of the values from the plot. The table and plot are updated every ~0.7 seconds.

Here is my main loop:

```
canvas.draw()
background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)
while True
    canvas.restore_region(background)
    [update data for lines, table]
    for line in lines:
        ax.draw_artist(line)
    canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
    for line in lines:
        line.set_animated(False)

    canvas.draw_idle()
    canvas.flush_events()

    for line in lines:
        line.set_animated(True)

    time.sleep(0.7)
```

This updates as I expect it to, and everything looks OK.

But then when I resize the plot window (by clicking and dragging the window edge) I start to see artifacts left over from apparently as the resize was occurring (it appears for maybe 0.1 second, so I can't attach a screenshot). Basically I see what appears to be an old plot and the border of my table for a very short time on each iteration through my main loop, then the plot and table display fine.

What I've Tried:
I registered a callback for 'resize_event' and in that case do:

```
canvas.restore_region(firstBackground)
canvas.draw_idle()
canvas.flush_events()
```

Then on the next iteration through the main loop behave like normal. My callback is running, but this doesn't seem to help the problem at all.

So I think I need to do a transform on the background I saved before any data was plotted and call restore_region with the transformed background, but I am not sure if I am missing something simple.

EDIT:
Some more information. The plot I am trying to blit has two axes in the same area(one was created by calling twinx() on the other axis)

So far I have tried:

1. Calling set_visible(False) on all lines, then drawing and getting a new background image. This shows the same glitch on resize.
2. Calling cla() on the two axes that overlap. This also shows the same glitch after resizing.

Comment: blitting saves the bitmap of the background, so  if you resize that bitmap is invalid.  You have to draw the background again

Comment: that makes sense. But I am not sure how to hide the lines for the canvas reset. Do I use set_visible(False) on each plotted line?